# Call Recorder Software Not Working

Tags: call-recording

I have installed automatic call recorder on my smartphone. The problem is that it really works fine for a couple of days or so but after that it automatically stops recording. But when I open it, then it again starts recording automatically. I have repeatedly re-installed the app but the response is the same. What can i do in this regard to keep recording going?

Comment: Have you exempted it from battery optimization under Settings app?

Comment: No i haven`t looked at that